# How to use bootstrap component which extends jQuery in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the bootstrap 3.3.7 popover component (I can't use the ng version) in a new angular 4 app, so I have installed:

```
npm install --save jquery @types/jquery bootstrap
```

Then I added the css and scripts to angular-cli.json

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.js"
  ]
```

Then in the `typings.d.ts` file I added an interface:

```
interface Jquery { 
   popover(...any) : any;
}
```

Then in my component I've imported the jQuery:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
```

but when I tried to execute the popover method I get a compilation error:

```
('#test1').popover('show'); //here i have a compilation error on the popover method.
```

How to make typescript recognize it?

Comment: `npm install --save jquery @types/jquery bootstrap` - obvious thing would be to install @types/bootstrap as well. Did you try that?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I got this to work on a new Angular project created with the cli:

```
npm install --save jquery bootstrap@3.3.7
```

Updated the `app.component.ts` to:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

declare const $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('div') divElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(this.divElement.nativeElement).popover({content: 'foobar', placement: 'bottom'}).popover('show');
  }
}
```

and `app.component.html` to

```
<div #div>hello there</div>
```

Since the scripts and styles additions to the `angular-cli.json` add these files to the global scope, doing the imports the way you have will only muddy the waters. This will cause jQuery to get imported for a second time and this time it will be after the bootstrap scripts.

In general, it is better to try to do the imports the way you have them as this will allow typescript/webpack to load the needed scripts and do some other build time magic. Due to the way that the bootstrap scripts in version 3 depend on jQuery though, the global scope scripts method seems to be a necessity.

In order to keep typescript from complaining then though, you need to tell it about the global jQuery object though and that is accomplished through the line `declare const $: any;`

Full GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-bootstrap%403.3.7)

Hope this helps!